# Combine friendly url and query string

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

How to make a working url like this: `example.com/controller/method?id=1&cat=2`

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't pass "id" and "cat" via URI segments? For example, example.com/controller/method/1/2 or example.com/controller/method/id/1/cat/2 ?

Comment: maybe because this url is created not by me, what other reasons can be?

Comment: dynback.com... we don't know. That's why we are asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible by setting `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;` in your config.php file (As [DamienL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868350/combine-friendly-url-and-query-string/2881176#2881176) answered). I just tried with a fresh CodeIgniter installation [from here](http://codeigniter.com/download.php).

**However, it appears there must be at least 2 variables (separated with a "&") for it to work.**

Here are the steps I took to make this happen:

In config.php, I changed `$config['base_url']` to the appropriate directory and set `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;`

In the controllers directory I created the following class:

```
class Testing extends Controller {

    function Testing()
    {
        parent::Controller();   
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}

/* End of file testing.php */

/* Location: ./system/application/controllers/testing.php */
```

I can then access the index function with a query string, but only if there are 2 or more variables like this:

> localhost/CodeIgniter_1.7-1.2/index.php/testing/index?id=123&cat=abc

If you absolutely need both the segment-based and query string-based approaches, but only need one variable in a particular query string, I suppose you could add a second "dummy" variable and just ignore it.

Comment: Your option is for this:
http://127.0.0.1/critic/index.php?c=testing&m=index&some=1 |
But I need this:
http://127.0.0.1/critic/index.php/testing/index?some=1

Comment: @dynaback.com: Why the -1? After enabling query strings, you *can* do 127.0.0.1/critic/index.php/testing/index?some=1. I'll edit my answer to clarify

Comment: I have 404 for this. When I set that option, only-segment and only-query-string become working. But not both in one url.

Comment: @dynback.com: I modified my answer to provide a more precise explanation (Note the part regarding the two query string variables). Also, did my response really warrant a -1?

Comment: yes, you really solved it. But in any case, why cant I put one query parameter ... strange

Comment: @dynback.com: Strange indeed - I'm not sure why that is. Glad you got it working though!