# How to extract get variable from query string in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

My issue is i have QUERY_STRING enabled in my codeigniter setup so that links look like this 
http://www.domain.com/search/index/page/4?squery=searchterm

I have a form on this page that uses GET because I can't use POST for what i'm using, when i try to retrieve the "squery" using `$this->uri->segment(4)` it doesn't return that part only the 4 part. What way can i retrieve the search term ?

This is in my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work by doing this 
Changing my config variables

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;  
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
```

And changing my htaccess to this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Help found here 
[How to make CodeIgniter accept "query string" URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894250/how-to-make-codeigniter-accept-query-string-urls)

Comment: Oh well I tried! +1 to you for finding your solution and posting it for others to see.