# Rewrite URL in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

How can I completely avoid using the Codeigniter method of handling URLs and use the conventional way?

Instead of `[root_url]/index.php/controller/view/data`, how can I just get `[root_url]/view.php?variable=value&variable=value etc ...`.

If it matters, I am running and testing the site locally and not on the net.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894250/how-to-make-codeigniter-accept-query-string-urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not intending on using CI for its URL handling, I would probably recommend using a different framework.

I would recommend keeping your entire application within the CodeIgniter scope. `[base_url]/view/?param=value` works just fine, and you can access GET requests via `$this->input->get('param');`

Another option is enabling `enable_query_strings`, which gives you some control over how controllers/functions are routed. Have a look at `enable_query_strings` in the documentation on URLS at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Alternatively, If you don't want view.php in your CI app, `[base_url]/view.php?param=value&etc=` should load, but it'll exist outside the CodeIgniter scope.

If it's not loading, make If you have an .htaccess file and are redirecting traffic, make sure you have !-f and !-d flags for the REQUEST_FILENAME enabled, so that view.php isn't being redirected:

```
$RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
$RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
$RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```