# CodeIgniter Mod Rewrite Rules and the Controller

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Learning PHP, I am playing around with mod_rewrite and CodeIgniter. I have configured my .htaccess file correctly with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(resources)/(.*) $1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(user_guide)/(.*) $1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [L]
```

I understand a bit of regex, and can appreciate what happens here. The rewrite rules are applied and the server than handles the final URL which in the above case- attaches index.php (the front controller) to the "pretty" URL. So far so good.

I now want a URL pattern :

```
/<person-name>/at/<place>
```

to get translated to :

```
/index.php/person/list?personName=$1&place=$2
```

And i handle the request at my list function in the person controller. I do not understand why the following doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(at)/([a-z]+)$ index.php/person/list?personName=$1&place=$2 [L]
```

What am i doing wrong/where is my understanding flawed? I see that the placeholders are extracted correctly ($1 and $3), however, it throws a CodeIgniter 404.

Many thanks!

Comment: could you not do in the `routes.php - `$route['([a-z]+)/at/([a-z]+)'] = "person/list/$1/$2";

Comment: Yes I did that eventually when i learnt about the routes.php. :-) I'm looking for an answer as to why i cannot do that at the .htaccess file. :-) Btw, why can't we access those $1 and $2 via the GET params? Does that work?

Comment: In your `config.php` are there both set to true? - `$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;`

Comment: enable_query_strings wasn't but i just made it TRUE and checked. Same story.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the simplest fix will fix your issue.  By wrapping "at" in parentheses, you're creating another matching group, which means that $2 will always be "at."  That could be breaking everything.  You want `index.php?person/list?personName=$1&place=$3`  But you may have noticed that issue and fixed it without fixing the problem, in which case, read on.

Check out [How to make CodeIgniter accept "query string" URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894250/how-to-make-codeigniter-accept-query-string-urls).  It seems to indicate that you can't mix and match the segment-based approach and the query string approach.  Without seeing your controller code, I can't say for certain, but I'd start investigating there.  You might also try:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(at)/([a-z]+)$ index.php?person/list/$1/$3 [L]
```

which would do the same thing the general-purpose CI redirect rule below does; send the URL off to index.php as a query string for processing.  You've said you got it working with routes, so rather than passing a query string to your controller, you can expect person and place as two arguments.  CI's handling of query strings leaves a lot to be desired, and I've never tried to MOD_REWRITE something including a query string into a query string.