# Extracting GET Parameters in CodeIgniter from the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

URL mapping can be done at .htaccess and we can edit routes.php. Learning PHP/Codeigniter, i posted this question. [CodeIgniter Mod Rewrite Rules and the Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274553/codeigniter-mod-rewrite-rules-and-the-controller)

routes.php worked for me, and the next thing i'd like is to have access to the GET parameters in my URL. To elaborate on what i'm actually trying to do:

**Case 1:**

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(at)/([a-z]+)$ index.php/person/show?personName=$1&place=$2 [L]
```

This doesn't work at the .htaccess as in the above question, but I can get that working in the routes.php

```
$route['([a-z]+)/at/([a-z]+)'] = "person/show/$1/$2";
```

If i try the routes.php as

```
$route['([a-z]+)/at/([a-z]+)'] = "person/show?personName=$1&place=$2";
```

I end up with a CodeIgniter 404. Is this fundamentally incorrect?

This works fine as is:

```
person/show?personName=chinmay&place=kino
```

**Case 2:**

URL which I want to expose:

```
chinmay?place=kino
```

where place is shown as a GET param. I would like to handle this, and knowing as much about routes.php-

```
$route['([a-z]+)\?place=([a-z]+)'] = "person/show/$1/$2"
```

This gives a CI 404 as well.

Comment: why go so cmplicated? isnt controller/method/param1/param2/param3/paramN enough? or you might like _remap() function... In my applications i try to have as less as possible entries in routes.php simply for simplicity. I use routes.php purely when i need to translate url to local language.

Answer (score 0):

[Passing URI Segments to your Functions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri)

or

[GET parameters in the URL with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334708/get-parameters-in-the-url-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
<?php

 function myFunction($param1, $param2){
  //code
 }
?>
```

And access it like: `.../controller/myFunction/param1/param2`