# How can i get query string variable value in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-string

I want to get query string variable value and allowed on config file for query string rule.

My Url :

```
http://localhost/Demo/admin_login/?mts=ok
```

I did in config file :

```
 $config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
 $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
 $config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

In controller, I echo this

```
echo $_GET['mts'];
```

I got this error :

```
Message:  Undefined index: mts
```

Comment: You use standard codeigniter format as `http://localhost/Demo/admin_login/ok` and get value and get value `echo $mts =$this->uri->segment(3);`

Comment: In your code you missed action `index`. Try to use `http://localhost/Demo/admin_login/index?mts=ok`

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2898004/3635079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your .htaccess to remove the ? (if present) in the rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

try 
[How to make CodeIgniter accept "query string" URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894250/how-to-make-codeigniter-accept-query-string-urls)

Comment: Query string works fine but now how to remove index.php from url ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url try this http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-htaccess-remove-index-php/